# Randomizing User class username

Tags: trigger, unit-test, dml

I have the following method:

```
public static User initUser(){
/**
    * Create a User
    * Insert User into DB
    * Return User back into testPage in order to use information    
**/

    User testUser = new User (
                // For future reference, make sure to write UserRoleID 
                // and ProfileId when creating new Users.
                lastName = 'Lastly', alias = 'newalias', 
                email = 'test@testOwnerId.com', username = user@testUser.com', 
                // Need to make username random and different in order 
                // to avoid SYstem.DMLException.
                // More fields here that I omitted );

    insert testUser;
    return testUser;
}
```

I need to find a way to randomize the username field above because if I don't, I receive a SYstem.DmlException.

I'm trying to do it using the Datetime.now method by doing this:

Datetime userDateTime = datetime.now();
username = userDateTime+'@test.com'

Unfortunately, I still receive a SYstem.DmlException which tells me the following error:

> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION username must be in the form of an email
>   address (for example,john@acme.com).

My question is how would I go about randomizing this username?
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usernames have to follow email format

You can use for example

```
Username = 'User' + Datime.now().getTime() + '@test.com';
```

Or using Math.Random

```
Username = 'User' + Math.random()*100 + '@test.com'
```

Comment: I'd strongly reccomend using your orgId as the domain (with some suffix like .test) to further reduce the change of collision. e.g. Username = 'User' + Math.random()*100 + '@'+UserInfo.getOrganizationId()+'.test';

Answer (score 4):

Your variable, *userDateTime*, probably has invalid characters for an email address. You could try using a base name and appending a random number, something similar to:

```
// Generate a random number for the username
// Add it to both the local part AND the domain to try to help ensure system-wide unique constraint
Double randomNum = Math.random();
string userName = 'test' + randomNum + '@test' + randomNum + '.com';
```

**Notes:**

1. Remember, usernames must be globally unique across *EVERY* Salesforce instance. This snippet may not always guarantee that
2. This has not been fully tested - it's an idea to get you started

Comment: that's what I suspected with the  format for datetime. It returns 
a format of the returned datetime as: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM which is most likely invalid. 

the above is a pretty good start. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method to create a test user that you could adapt from the [Force Adventure blog](http://forceadventure.wordpress.com/2013/04/11/creating-test-users/):

```
public static User createTestUser(Id roleId, Id profID, String fName, String lName) {
    String orgId = userInfo.getOrganizationId();
    String dateString = String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');
    Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));
    String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;
    User tuser = new User(  firstname = fName,
                            lastName = lName,
                            email = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org',
                            Username = uniqueName + '@test' + orgId + '.org',
                            EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
                            Alias = uniqueName.substring(18, 23),
                            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                            ProfileId = profId,
                            UserRoleId = roleId);
    return tuser;
}
```